# Small result query with LIMIT 1000x slower than queries with >100 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am trying to debug a query that runs faster the more records it returns but performance severely degrades (>10x slower) with smaller returns (i.e. <10 rows) using small `LIMIT` (ie 10).

Example:

Fast query with 5 results out of 1M rows - no LIMIT

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaction_internal_by_addresses
WHERE address = 'foo'
ORDER BY block_number desc;
```

Explain:

```
Sort  (cost=7733.14..7749.31 rows=6468 width=126) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=5 loops=1)
"  Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
  Sort Key: transaction_internal_by_addresses.block_number
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
  Buffers: shared hit=10
  ->  Index Scan using transaction_internal_by_addresses_pkey on public.transaction_internal_by_addresses  (cost=0.69..7323.75 rows=6468 width=126) (actual time=0.018..0.021 rows=5 loops=1)
"        Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
        Index Cond: (transaction_internal_by_addresses.address = 'foo'::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=10
Query Identifier: -8912211611755432198
Planning Time: 0.051 ms
Execution Time: 0.041 ms
```

Fast query with 5 results out of 1M rows: - High LIMIT

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaction_internal_by_addresses
WHERE address = 'foo'
ORDER BY block_number desc
LIMIT 100;
```

```
Limit  (cost=7570.95..7571.20 rows=100 width=126) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=5 loops=1)
"  Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
  Buffers: shared hit=10
  ->  Sort  (cost=7570.95..7587.12 rows=6468 width=126) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=5 loops=1)
"        Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
        Sort Key: transaction_internal_by_addresses.block_number DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        Buffers: shared hit=10
        ->  Index Scan using transaction_internal_by_addresses_pkey on public.transaction_internal_by_addresses  (cost=0.69..7323.75 rows=6468 width=126) (actual time=0.016..0.020 rows=5 loops=1)
"              Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
              Index Cond: (transaction_internal_by_addresses.address = 'foo'::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=10
Query Identifier: 3421253327669991203
Planning Time: 0.042 ms
Execution Time: 0.034 ms
```

Slow query: - Low LIMIT

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaction_internal_by_addresses
WHERE address = 'foo'
ORDER BY block_number desc
LIMIT 10;
```

Explain result:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.63..6133.94 rows=10 width=126) (actual time=10277.845..11861.269 rows=0 loops=1)
"  Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
  Buffers: shared hit=56313576
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.63..3333036.90 rows=6491 width=126) (actual time=10277.844..11861.266 rows=0 loops=1)
"        Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        Buffers: shared hit=56313576
        ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using transaction_internal_by_address_idx_block_number on public.transaction_internal_by_addresses  (cost=0.57..3331263.70 rows=1623 width=126) (actual time=10256.995..10256.995 rows=0 loops=5)
"              Output: address, block_number, log_index, transaction_hash"
              Filter: (transaction_internal_by_addresses.address = 'foo'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 18485480
              Buffers: shared hit=56313576
              Worker 0:  actual time=10251.822..10251.823 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=11387166
              Worker 1:  actual time=10250.971..10250.972 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=10215941
              Worker 2:  actual time=10252.269..10252.269 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=10191990
              Worker 3:  actual time=10252.513..10252.514 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=10238279
Query Identifier: 2050754902087402293
Planning Time: 0.081 ms
Execution Time: 11861.297 ms
```

**DDL**

```sql
create table transaction_internal_by_addresses
(
    address          text   not null,
    block_number     bigint,
    log_index        bigint not null,
    transaction_hash text   not null,
    primary key (address, log_index, transaction_hash)
);

alter table transaction_internal_by_addresses
    owner to "icon-worker";

create index transaction_internal_by_address_idx_block_number
    on transaction_internal_by_addresses (block_number);
```

##### So my questions

- Should I just be looking at ways to force the query planner to apply the WHERE on the `address` (primary key)?
- As you can see in the explain, the row `block_number` is scanned in the slow query but I am not sure why. Can anyone explain?
- Is this normal? Seems like the more data, the harder the query, not the other way around as in this case.

#### Update

- Apologies for A, the delay in responding and B, some of the inconsistencies in this question.
- I have updated the EXPLAIN clearly showing the 1000x performance degradation

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, COSTS) for both queries? And the DDL for this table, including the indexes. And did you ANALYZE this table?

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` for your `slow` query does not match the query. The query is over `transaction_internal_by_addresses` whereas the `EXPLAIN` is showing: `... Index Scan using a_table_pkey on public.a_table ...`. Where is ` public.a_table` coming from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Judging by the edit history it initially was an attempt at obfuscating relation names that OP later abandoned and tried to overwrite, overlooking some leftovers.

Comment: `a_table_pkey` doesn't make sense. Please present a consistent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multicolumn BTREE index on `(address, block_number DESC)` is exactly what the query planner needs to generate the result sets you mentioned. It will random-access the index to the first eligible row, then read the rows out in sequential order until it hits the LIMIT. You can also omit the DESC with no ill effects.

```
create index address_block_number
on transaction_internal_by_addresses
 (address, block_number DESC);
```

As for asking "why" about query planner results, that's often an enduring mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Sub-millisecond differences are hardly predictable so you're pretty much staring at noise, random miniscule differences caused by other things happening on the system. Your fastest query runs in tens of **micro**seconds, slowest in a single **milli**second - all of these are below typical network, mouse click, screen refresh latencies.

1. The planner already applies a `where` on your `address`: *Index Cond: (a_table.address = 'foo'::text)*
2. You're ordering by `block_number`, so it makes sense to scan it. It's also taking place in all three of your queries because they all do that.
3. It is normal - [here's an online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_lBHLdKe) with similar differences. If what you're after is some reliable time estimation, use [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) to run your queries multiple times and average out the timings.

Your third query plan seems to be coming from a different query, against a different table: **`a_table`**, compared to the initial two: **`transaction_internal_by_addresses`**.

If you were just wondering why these timings look like that, it's pretty much random and/or irrelevant at this level. If you're facing some kind of problem because of how these queries behave, it'd be better to focus on describing that problem - the queries themselves all do the same thing and the difference in their execution times is negligible.

Comment: Really apologize for delay in responding and the inconsistencies in the question. I have updated the EXPLAIN showing the 1000x performance degradation. Really appreciate your reply. If you have any other thoughts, please update your thoughtful answer.

Comment: I think that at this point it might make more sense to ask a new, cleaned-up version of the question. The more you update the question, the less relevant all surrounding comments and answers become, making the whole thing unreadable, chaotic and unlikely to be useful to people searching for a similar problem in the future. You're also less likely to attract new eyes to an old thread with the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should I just be looking at ways to force the query planner to apply the WHERE on the address (primary key)?

- Yes, it can be improve performance

2. As you can see in the explain, the row block_number is scanned in the slow query but I am not sure why. Can anyone explain?

- Because Sort keys are different. Look carefully:

  `Sort Key: transaction_internal_by_addresses.block_number DESC` 
   `Sort Key: a_table.a_indexed_row DESC`

  it seems `a_table.a_indexed_row` has less performant stuff (eg more columns, more complex structure etc.)

3. Is this normal? Seems like the more data, the harder the query, not the other way around as in this case.

- Normally more queries cause more time. But as I mentioned above, maybe `a_table.a_indexed_row` returns more values, has more columns etc.